# What does it mean for all values of a type must use the same amount of memory in Rust?

Tags: rust

**Forgive me if there is an obvious answer to the question I'm asking, but I just don't quite understand it.**

The [Dynamically Sized Types and the Sized Trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait) section in chapter 19.3 Advanced Types of the 《The Rust Programming Language》 mentions:

> Rust needs to know how much memory to allocate for any value of a particular type, and all values of a type must use the same amount of memory. If Rust allowed us to write this code, these two `str` values would need to take up the same amount of space. But they have different lengths: `s1` needs 12 bytes of storage and `s2` needs 15. This is why it’s not possible to create a variable holding a dynamically sized type.

When it says "and all values of a type must use the same amount of memory", it is meant to refer to *dynamically sized types*, not types such as vectors or arrays, right? `v1` and `v2` are also unlikely to occupy the same amount of memory.

```rust
let v1 = vec![1, 2, 3];
let v2 = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
```

Comment: A vector is just a pointer to the heap, capacity and length, therefore its size is always the same. As for arrays, the size of an array is part of it's type.

Comment: I see, it's like what Silvio Mayolo said: "it only refers to the size of the structure itself, not to the recursive size of all things it points to". In the case of array, `[i32; 5]` will only occupy the same amount of memory as `[i32; 5]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct and considers vectors as well. A `Vec<T>` is roughly just a pointer to a position on the heap, a capacity, and a length. It could be defined, more or less, as

```
pub struct Vec<T>(T*, usize, usize);
```

And every value of *that* structure clearly has the same size. When Rust says that every value of a type has to have the same size, it only refers to the size of the structure itself, not to the recursive size of all things it points to. `Box<T>` has a constant size, regardless of `T`, which is why `Box` can hold even things that are dynamically sized, such as trait objects. Likewise, `String` is basically just a pointer.

Likewise, if we define

```
pub enum MyEnum {
  A(i32),
  B(i32, i32),
}
```

Then `MyEnum::A` is no smaller than `MyEnum::B`, for similar reasons, despite the latter having more data than the former.

Comment: I get it, it's like `&str`, a `&str` is two values: the address of the `str` and its length. That is, we always know the size of a `&str`, no matter how long the string it refers to is. The same is true for `MyEnum::A` and `MyEnum::B`, "it only refers to the size of the structure itself, not to the recursive size of all things it points to".

Comment: Note that there is a difference in the `MyEnum` case: there are no extra "things it points to". Instead the `MyEnum::A` case contains an extra 4 bytes of padding to bring it to the same size as `MyEnum::B`.

Answer (score 2):

Every type that can be stored and accessed without the indirection of a reference or `Box` must have the `Sized` trait implemented. This means that every instance of the type will have the same size. A `str` is a DST, as the data it holds can be of a variable length, and thus, you can only access `str`s as references, or from `String`, which holds the `str` data on the heap, through a pointer.

Every `Vec` also takes the same space, which is 24 bytes on a 64-bit machine.

For example:

```rust
let vec = vec![1, 2, 3, 4];
println!("{}", std::mem::size_of_val(&vec)); // Prints '24'.
```

Comment: I get it, it's like `&str`, a `&str` is two values: the address of the `str` and its length. That is, we always know the size of a `&str`, no matter how long the string it refers to is.